# how to apply click() to a tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, click

I am trying to emulate a click on a basic link that appears like this with no id or class.

```
<a href="http://www.myebsite.com/service/playnow">Click to Start</a>
```

I have the following code but when i load the page to no click action is performed. What am I doing wrong?

```
    var a = document.evaluate( '//a[contains(@href, "playnow")]' ,document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
    if(a){
        a.click();
    }
```

Comment: What browser?  Firefox doesn't/didn't have a "click()" method on `<a>` DOM elements, I don't think.

Comment: Is there a reason why the tag has no ID?  Have you verified `a` in fact has a value (maybe put a `window.alert(a);` before the `click()` call to verify)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why your tag doesn't have an ID is strange, but I'll assume for some reason you can't control that.  I don't think you can emulate a click through a "click" method, so perhaps try something like:

```
var a = document.evaluate( '//a[contains(@href, "playnow")]' ,document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
if(a){
   window.location.href = a.href;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to add an id to the anchor tag and then invoke the `click` function on the DOM element

HTML:

```
<a id="theAnchor" href="http://www.myebsite.com/service/playnow">Click to Start</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('theAnchor').click();
```

Comment: thank you I have this method too, but i plan on using this for a chrome extension also and in some instances i won't be able to add the id tag. is there another way